# Изменение TextView в зависимости от EditText

Tags: java, android

Я хочу, чтобы в зависимости от того, какое число пользователь вводит в `EditText`, в тот же момент менялся `TextView`.
 Я нашел класс `TextWatcher`, но по моему, он может считывать количество символов, а не их значения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы нашди правильный инструмент и он умеет то, что вам надо. Используйте примерно так:

```
final TextView textView = ...;
final EditText editText = ...;
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        textView.setText(s.toString());
    }
});
```

Comment: Можете объяснить как он работает?)) Сколько статей не прочитал все равно не до конца понимаю. Например что такое s в синтаксисе.

Comment: @AleksandrKim строка которая получилась в результате изменения. По моему это довольно очевидно(и по этому вы  не смогли найти информации по этому поводу:) вы всегда можете заглянуть в реализацию методов и посмотреть там.